# Extract XML/JSON element from Zillow API response and populate into Gravity Forms field

Tags: rest-api, plugin-gravity-forms, xml

Given this stack:

WordPress 5.3
GravityForms 2.4.15.6 (paid: common, right?)
Forms: 3rd-Party Integration (free: [Link to WordPress plugin page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/forms-3rdparty-integration/))
Forms: 3rd-Party Inject Results (free: [Link to WordPress plugin page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/forms-3rd-party-inject-results/))
Zillow GetSearchResults API (free: [Link to Zillow API](https://www.zillow.com/howto/api/GetSearchResults.htm))

I've connected to Zillow's API and received the response contained in this file: [Link to 3rd-Party Integration debug text file](https://www.killerdesigner.com/wp-content/uploads/forms-3rd-party-debug-response.txt).

Now that I've connected, I am supposed to be able to extract either XML or JSON and replace/overwrite the contents of a given field (input_12) within the originating Gravity Form (or in my case, the confirmation) (visible here: [link to Gravity Form)](http://killerdesigner.com/instant-home-valuation/) by following the instructions here [link to 3rd Party Inject Results instructions on GitHub](https://github.com/zaus/forms-3rdparty-inject-results) using a syntax that I simply can't figure out - something like:

*XML*

```
[env:Envelope/env:Body/ns1:Response/ns1:Resultstatus] => foo
[env:Envelope/env:Body/ns1:Response/ns1:Result] => bar
[env:Envelope/env:Body/ns1:Response/ns1:Description] => baz
```

or

*JSON*

```
[Body/Response/ResultStatus] => foo
[Body/Response/Result] => bar
[Body/Response/Description] => baz
```

in the Forms: 3rd-Party Inject Results field shown here: [Dropbox screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g6dqhgxs269d7y6/Screenshot%202019-11-17%2023.43.02.png?dl=0)

I am attempting to extract/display the "zestimate" element's "amount" field, but can't figure out the correct syntax/response path.

The successful Zillow XML response, along with the field(s) I need to capture can be seen in the text file here [link to Zillow XML response](https://www.killerdesigner.com/wp-content/uploads/zillow_xml_response.txt)

I have searched high and low, but correct syntax/formatting information is scarce on this specific topic/plugin, and I would like to accomplish this in the aforementioned stack, if at all possible.

I would greatly appreciate a guru's guidance in helping me format the correct syntax so I can get on with my freaking life. lol

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

the first step is to extract the value with this kind of code, does it work for you ?

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
$value = (string) $xml->response->results->result->zestimate->amount;

var_export($value, FALSE);
```

the next step is to put the value in the form. the Gravity Form is not free then we cannot test it and I only find that in documentation : https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_get_field_value/
if that doesn't help, you have to ask to gravity form support.

Comment: Thank you Kaperto! I will test it and report back.

Comment: Kaperto, is this a PHP function to be included in the functions.php? I entered the field path you specified (response/results/result/zestimate/amount) into the Forms: 3rd-Party Inject Results field shown above (in the freshly added screenshot) to no avail. I would prefer to accomplish this in the plugin itself, if at all possible.

Comment: functions.php is here to customise the theme. read this to develop a plugin : https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/